# Error code on startup on a 2008 iMac

Tags: wireless, bluetooth, startup, error-handling

I recently acquired a very old iMac and thought I would repurpose it and install the latest version of Ubuntu. Everything worked except for the wifi card. This was fixed when I installed additional software. The one thing that I can't understand is an error code on startup. It doesn't appear to be doing anything to the system since it still starts up and works. I have noticed a lag on startup. I'm assuming it's from the error code. How do I get this to go away? The code is Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0x0000. I'm completely new to Ubuntu and know little about terminal so please explain it to me like a child.
Here is my network card info if that helps:

```
*-network                 
   description: Wireless interface
   product: BCM4321 802.11a/b/g/n
   vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
   logical name: wls4
   version: 03
   serial: 00:1c:b3:75:e7:a9
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.271 (r587334) ip=192.168.1.197 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:16 memory:d0300000-d0303fff memory:d0000000-d00fffff
```

[image]